# Why do I get different openssl versions?

Tags: linux, centos6, yum, openssl, heartbleed

I'm trying to check if I running the latest OpenSSL version, my main concern is the heartbleed bug.

I tried 2 commands:

- `openssl version`
- `yum info openssl`

  ---

  **`openssl version` output**

  > OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

  ---

  **`yum info openssl` output**

  > Installed Packages
  >
  > Name        : openssl
  >
  > Arch        : x86_64
  >
  > Version     : 1.0.1e
  >
  > Release     : 16.el6_5.14
  >
  > ...

  ---

I have a couple of questions:

1. Why do I get different versions from these 2 commands?
2. How do I check the heartbleed vulnerability without having the 443 port open?

Answer (score 8):

The name of the RPM package is simply not the same as the version the software itself returns.

One of the reasons for that is Red Hat & CentOS [backports](https://access.redhat.com/site/security/updates/backporting/) security updates and bug fixes to the software version that was initially shipped. They take a fix for a security flaw out of the most recent version of an upstream software package i.e. openssl 1.0.1h and apply that fix to an older version of the package was distributed :  i.e. openssl 1.0.1e. That policy is the reason for a patch level string in the package name in addition to the software version number.

The version output of the `openssl version` command remains unchanged 1.0.1e regardless of your actual patch level.

`rpm -q --changelog openssl` shows which updates the package maintainer has included in the version you have currently installed.

The most current version shows:

```
* Mon Jun 02 2014 Tom Mraz <tmraz redhat.com> 1.0.1e-16.14
- fix CVE-2010-5298 - possible use of memory after free
- fix CVE-2014-0195 - buffer overflow via invalid DTLS fragment
- fix CVE-2014-0198 - possible NULL pointer dereference
- fix CVE-2014-0221 - DoS from invalid DTLS handshake packet
- fix CVE-2014-0224 - SSL/TLS MITM vulnerability
- fix CVE-2014-3470 - client-side DoS when using anonymous ECDH

* Mon Apr 07 2014 Tom Mraz <tmraz redhat.com> 1.0.1e-16.7
- fix CVE-2014-0160 - information disclosure in TLS heartbeat extension
```